# How to bind a List using @ModelAttribute to controller from a JSP form

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to get a list of selected candidates to my controller using @modelAttribute with their respective id and blurb. I am able to bring one Candidate correctly but i don't know how to bring a list of candidates thru... I tried to add List<> as i have shown below, but i get

> ERROR - 
>   SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/panel-requests] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [java.util.List]: Specified class is an interface] with root cause
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [java.util.List]: Specified class is an interface

JSP -

```
<form:form modelAttribute="candidateAddAttribute" 
  action="/panel-requests/requests/${panelRequestForId.id}/empl" method="post">
<c:forEach items="${candidates}" var="candidates">
    <select name="employee" id="employee" disabled="disabled">
        <option value="default" selected="selected">${candidates.candidateName}</option>
    </select>
    <textarea rows="3" cols="40" id="candidateBlurb" name="candidateBlurb" 
      disabled="disabled">${candidates.candidateBlurb}</textarea>

    <textarea rows="2" cols="20" id="candidateCV" name="candidateCV"                                
      disabled="disabled">${candidates.candidateCV}</textarea>
</c:forEach>
<div id="candidateDiv" id="candidateDiv">
    <select name="employee" id="employee">
        <option value="default" selected="selected">Select Employee</option>
        <c:forEach items="${employees}" var="employee">
            <option value="${employee.id}" id="${employee.id}">
                ${employee.employeeName}- ${employee.employeeCV}<
            /option>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>   
    <textarea rows="3" cols="40" id="candidateBlurb"                
      name="candidateBlurb">BLURB</textarea>
    <div id="employeeCv"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="Add Candidate" />
</div>
</form:form>
```

The above form at first displays list of employee and when user selects employee, enters blurb and hits add candidate button, i take data to controller.

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{id}/empl", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String getEmployeeDetails(
    @ModelAttribute("candidateAddAttribute") @Valid List<Candidate> candidates,
    BindingResult result, @PathVariable("id") int requestId, Model model) {

        //implementation goes here
}
```

How do I implement List in this case? Thanks in advance.

**EDITED PART**
I tried sending 2 candidate's details, firebug sends it correctly like - 
Parameters
candidateBlurb  BLURB sar
candidateBlurb  BLURB dann
employee    1
employee    2

so it can be a problem in initBinder that i ma using, 
binder.registerCustomEditor(Employee.class,
                new PropertyEditorSupport() {
                    public String getAsText() {
                        return Long.toString(((Employee) getValue()).getId());
                    }

```
                public void setAsText(final String text) {
                    Employee employee = Employee.findById(Integer
                            .parseInt(text));
                    setValue(employee);
                }
            });
```

which only takes 1 employee detail at a time. Is that a problem here???

Answer (score 5):

Create a POJO class which contains the List as a property, such as

```
public class EmployeeForm {
     private List<Candidate> candidates;
     public List<Candidate> getCandidates() { ... }
     public void setCandidates(List<Candidates>) { ... }
}
```

and use this in your @RequestMapping method's signature rather than a `List<Candidate>` directly.

The error message you get is Spring complaining that it doesn't know how to instantiate a List interface, in order for Spring to bind the request parameters in the form to it. You want to provide a simple form/command class to data-bind the form parameters to, Spring knows how to handle a list from there.

Comment: Hi, i tried as u adviced, but i might be wrong somewhr, cud u plz guide me?

Comment: public class EmployeeForm { private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(EmployeeForm.class);
 private List<Candidate> candidates = new ArrayList<Candidate>();      
 public List<Candidate> getCandidates() { return candidates; }      
 public void setCandidates(List<Candidate> candidates) { this.candidates = candidates; } 
}
@RequestMapping(value = "{id}/empl", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String getEmployeeDetails(
   @ModelAttribute("candidateAddAttribute") @Valid EmployeeForm candidates,
   BindingResult result, @PathVariable("id") int requestId, Model model) {//code}

Comment: when i debug the above code, candidates is null when i try to use it in my controller... shud i change something in the code?

Comment: also, when i try to see  LOG.error(candidates.getCandidates().get(0).getCandidateBlurb()); in my controller, i get ERROR - SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/panel-requests] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0] with root cause
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Comment: what does the form data sent in the request look like? IIRC you should have a list of items like candidates[0].name, candidates[0].age, candidates[1].name etc

Comment: i don't know how to create such a dynamic list here. firebug tells me that only one candidate is sent (candidateBlurb,employeeId)... but not an array. when i check the post, candidateBlur BLURB345
employee 1 are given. How to sned a list from JSP?

Comment: as you loop through the candidates list in the JSP, increment a counter so that the name of your form elements is `candidates[i].name`, etc

Comment: Hi matt... Now i get output in the candidates[i].name format. But still the binding doesn't happen... Still controller gets it null.. what can i do now?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
List<Candidate> candidates = ListUtils.lazyList(new ArrayList<Candidate>(),FactoryUtils.instantiateFactory(Candidate.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this same issue, half of the fields are binding correctly and half aren't.  I noticed that the half that are not binding correctly (thus giving me NULL in the controller) were wrapped in a DIV.

When I moved these fields outside the DIV, bingo, they were bound properly in the controller.

I see that you have some fields wrapped in a DIV too, I'd recommend moving them out and seeing if they become visible to your controller.